# C++ Can't print certain words from Char array

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, char, format

Not sure how to phrase the question, but I'm making a program for an assignment, which we're not allowed to use pre-existing libraries besides input/output. We also can only use primitive data-types. I have to read a text file with words, remove all punctuation from the word, and then store those words in a 2D array of characters.

This problem seems to be that when a word starts with a non-alphabetic character, the whole word doesn't output when using `cout << stack[top]` but when I output each individual character with `cout << stack[top][i]`, it produces the expected output.

'stack' is a 2D array which contains characters to make up words.

'top' is a variable to represent the length of stack

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void push(char word[]);
char formatCharacter(char letter);
bool isAlphabet(char letter);
char toLowercase(char letter);

// Global Variables
const int STACK_SIZE = 50000;
const int WORD_SIZE = 30;
char stack[STACK_SIZE][WORD_SIZE];
int top = 0;
int words = 0;
int wordCount[STACK_SIZE];    

int main(){
    // Local Variables
    char filename[20];
    ifstream fin;
    char word[WORD_SIZE];

    // Get file input
    cerr << "Please enter the name of the input file: ";
    cin >> filename;

    // Open file
    fin.open(filename);
    // Print error if file doesn't open, then quit the program.
    if (!fin) {
        cerr << "Error opening file " << filename << ". Program will exit." << endl;
        return 0; 
    }

    // Read the file into the stack
    while (fin >> word) {
        push(word);
    }

    // Close file
    fin.close();
}

void push(char word[]){
    if (top == STACK_SIZE) return;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    do {
        if (isAlphabet(word[i])){
            word[i] = formatCharacter(word[i]);
            stack[top][i] = word[i];
            cout << stack[top][i]; // Output fine
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    } while (word[i]);

    wordCount[words] = j;
    //cout << stack[top] << ": " << wordCount[words] << endl; // Output incorrect
    cout << endl;
    top++;
    words++;
    return;
}

bool isAlphabet(char letter){
    if ((letter < 'A' || letter > 'Z') && (letter < 'a' || letter > 'z')){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

char formatCharacter(char letter){
    if ((letter < 'A' || letter > 'Z') && (letter < 'a' || letter > 'z')){
        letter = '\0';
    }
    else{
        if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'){
            letter = toLowercase(letter);
        }
    }
    return letter;
}

char toLowercase(char letter){
    letter = letter + 32;
    return letter;
}
```

isAlphabet() just checks if it's an alphabetic character

formatCharacter() removes any punctuation by replacing the character with '\0', and also changes uppercase to lowercase.

Input:

```
Jabberwocky

'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
```

Output when using `cout << stack[top][i]`:

```
jabberwocky
twas
brillig
and
the
slithy
toves
did
gyre
and
gimble
in
the
wabe
all
mimsy
were
the
borogoves
and
the
mome
raths
outgrabe
```

Output when using `cout << stack[top]`:

```
jabberwocky: 11
: 4
brillig: 7
and: 3
the: 3
slithy: 6
toves: 5
did: 3
gyre: 4
and: 3
gimble: 6
in: 2
the: 3
wabe: 4
all: 3
mimsy: 5
were: 4
the: 3
borogoves: 9
and: 3
the: 3
mome: 4
raths: 5
outgrabe: 8
```

Notice the word 'twas' is missing. I'd rather not loop through each character of each word to get the output I need. I'd appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: *isAlphabet() just checks if it's an alphabetic character* -- You should be using [std::isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and not your own homemade function.  Also, what is `stack`?  You should post a [mcve], as per StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: I'm aware, as I said, we're not allowed to use any pre-existing libraries

Comment: `cout` is part of a preexisting library.  You cannot write any meaningful C++ program without calling a library function.

Comment: Besides input and output, we have to do everything else ourselves. We can only use primitive data-types. Updated the question.

Comment: Once again, please post a [mcve].  We have no idea where, when, or how `top` is created, what value it has, etc.

Comment: *"formatCharacter() removes any punctuation by replacing the character with '\0',"* - so what do you think that does to a string? Ex: a string of `'Twas` ? That dumps a terminator at the start of what *was* a string; now it's *empty* to anyone that expects a terminated string (since you just dumped a terminator into the first char). Works fine on non-alpha *trailing* strings, but anywhere else just truncs the string, in the case of 'twas, to an *empty* string. Now, if you want *real* help post a proper [mcve].

Comment: And to @WhozCraig's point, if you were to "break your rules" and simply called `strlen` on the value of `word[i]`, you would see that it is 0 for `'Twas`.  Regardless of what rule some teacher put on you, there is nothing stopping you from using library functions for your own debugging purposes.  Then once the program has been debugged, then go back to your home-made code.

Comment: Not allowed to use any of the existing types. Sounds like a datastructures class to me, just know in practice the guideline is to do it the other way around and use classes like std::stack & std::string. I just hope your teacher will point that out at some time too (if not: point that out to him)

Comment: Updated the code. I get what '\0' is now. Thanks.

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- If it is data structures, then the teacher is super-paranoid if the student can't use something like `std::string` or even `std::isalpha`, where neither one has very little, if anything, to do with data structures.

Comment: @McYellowBird `if ((letter < 'A' || letter > 'Z') && (letter < 'a' || letter > 'z'))` -- Well, your teacher doesn't know how to test for alphabetic characters.  This is not the way you do it -- there is no guarantee that the letters are contiguous (i.e. EBCDIC), and this does not cover non-English alphabetic characters.  That's the reason `std::isalpha` is used, because the system knows what is an alphabetic character.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my subject is Algorithms and Data Structures, and he requires us to only use primitive data types, as well as only using iostream and fstream for inputs/outputs

Comment: `std::isalpha` is not a data type.  It just takes your character and returns a value.  A typical data structures class will disallow `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::make_heap`, etc.  as those are actual data structures implemented in C++.  Not allowing `std::isalpha` `std::string`, even `strlen` makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, it'd be good to use that but he wants us to create our own functions, which are mainly based off of the course content.

Comment: @McYellowBird -- Yes, but if someone were to put in a foreign alphabetic character in your file, your code will miss it completely.  So basically your test only works for the default locale (English), and ASCII.  Just for your information -- you might as well learn good coding habits when given a chance.

Comment: @McYellowBird `if ((letter < 'A' || letter > 'Z') && (letter < 'a' || letter > 'z')){ letter = '\0';` -- So now you know the issue, how do you propose to fix it?  You can't simply stick a `\0` there, as `std::cout::operator<<` will terminate the output when that character is detected.  The restriction that you can't use `std::string` makes this all the more clumsy, as `std::string` you can actually remove characters, and not fake removal by sticking a `\0` inside the string.  Basically you're stuck on stuff that has nothing to do with data structures.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The code only needs to work for 2 input files, both of which containing English and ASCII characters.

Comment: *I'd rather not loop through each character of each word to get the output I need* -- Well, that's your best option at this point, given the restriction.  You simply have to output character by character in a loop that is `WORD_SIZE` in size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I know, I got the feeling most teachers are still stuck pre C++98 to be honest. And I think datastructures can be taught using more modern approaches too. Another bleak option is that the teachers like to see students struggle with manual memory managment and all the bugs attached to that :(

Comment: Sometime I just would like to have a constructive chat with teachers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix is to change:

```
stack[top][i] = word[i];
```

To:

```
stack[top][j] = word[i];
           ^ j not i here
```

This will ensure that the `'Twas` ends up as `twas` and not `\0twas`.

Also, `formatCharacter()` should call `isAlphabet()` rather than repeat the condition.